# cannot access function from factory through directive in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

/*TypeError: Cannot read property 'getToken' of undefined*/
I am trying to call getToken function which is defined in the factory function.

Both directive and factories are in separate .js file
but it is throwing an error and is not able to access the function.

```
angular.module('pesaveWeb')
  .directive('goals', function goalsDrctv ($timeout) {
    'use strict';
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      scope: true,
      templateUrl: "js/directives/goals.tmpl.html",
      controllerAs: 'savings',
      controller: function ($routeParams, $scope, 
       savingsFactory,tokenFactory) {

        this.message = {};

        var token=tokenFactory.getToken();
        var getGoals = savingsFactory.getGoals(token);
        if (getGoals) {
          getGoals.then( angular.bind(this, function (response) {
            savingsFactory.message = response;
            this.message = savingsFactory.message;
             alert(JSON.stringify(this.message));  

          }) );
        }
      }

    }
  });



angular.module('pesaveWeb').factory('tokenFactory', function tokenFactory ($http,$routeParams) {
    'use strict';
    var obj = {};


    obj.getToken = function () {

        return $http({
          method: 'POST', 
          url: "../api/v1/getToken", 
          headers : {
                    'Content-Type':'application/json',
                    'X-API-KEY':'04g4g00c04ks4sokgkoosg0kwww0cww4www0kc80',
                    'Authorization':"Basic cGVzYXZlQXBwOkNDNTVzV0FwUW0zYWxpazlLNTcwTTFXQ1RNOUJ1TmZS"
                },
          data: {"grant_type":"client_credentials"}
        }) .success(function (data) {


          })
          .error(function (data) {
          });

    };

  });
```

Comment: You need to return `obj` from factory. Add a `return obj;` statement to the end of your factory code.

Comment: Worked..Thanks!!!

Comment: Another potential problem in the code. Check out the answer I have posted.

Comment: Hey can you tell me the reason..m stuck elsewhere

Comment: The reason being you're returning `$http()` and not `data` as received in the  `.success()` callback. Hence, you need to use a promise to return  `data` in the `success()` callback... If you're facing another problem than mentioned in the original post, please accept the answer and post that specific problem in another question.

Answer (score 0):

Your factory function needs to return the `obj` you are using to bind the function to.

```
angular.module('pesaveWeb').factory('tokenFactory', function tokenFactory ($http,$routeParams) {
    'use strict';
    var obj = {};


    obj.getToken = function () {

        return $http({
          method: 'POST', 
          url: "../api/v1/getToken", 
          headers : {
                    'Content-Type':'application/json',
                    'X-API-KEY':'04g4g00c04ks4sokgkoosg0kwww0cww4www0kc80',
                    'Authorization':"Basic cGVzYXZlQXBwOkNDNTVzV0FwUW0zYWxpazlLNTcwTTFXQ1RNOUJ1TmZS"
                },
          data: {"grant_type":"client_credentials"}
        }) .success(function (data) {


          })
          .error(function (data) {
          });

    };
    return obj;
  });
```

Also, another potential problem is the `getToken()` function might not work as expected. You should use a "promise" for resolving the value of token in your `getToken()` function using Angular's `$q` service. Check out its [documentation here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)